# Problemas convitiendo una variable String a Integer en PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Mi problema es que cuando deseo tranformar una variable de JS capturada com prompt a una variable de PHP el valor obtenido es siempre cero. He usado varias formas en PHP y siempre obtengo al final un entero pero con valor cero. he aquí el codigo:

```
<Doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script>
            var temp;
            temp=parseInt(window.prompt('Write a temperature',''));
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $stemp = "<script> document.write(temp) </script>";
            $phptemp = intval($stemp);
            echo "The value of \$phptemp is : $phptemp <br>";
            if (!is_nan($phptemp)){
                if ($phptemp < 0 || $phptemp > 38){
                    echo "Don't go outside, better stay in house today!!!.";
                }
                else {
                    echo "You can go outside, it's a nice day.";
                }
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Tengo problemas al convertir una variable tipo String en PHP a un entero. He usado todas las formas de conversión, el dato llega como cadena con numero pero a convertirla siempre se convierte en cero.

Comment: El principal problema es que estás queriendo ejecutar código php del lado del cliente cuando eso es imposible. Cuando tu prompt se abre, nada de tu código en php se ejecutará, de hecho ni siquiera se puede ver dentro del DOM porque este fue procesado, ni siquiera ocupas php para lo que necesitas, con puro JS puedes hacer lo que necesitas.

Comment: Pero cuando reviso el contenido de $stemp contiene el valor que ingrese en JS, el problema es que al tratar de convertirlo a entero en PHP se convierte en cero.

Comment: Hay alguna razón en especial para la que se tenga que usar PHP? Fuera de ser un ejercicio escolar, puedes cambiar la lógica a JS y no darte de topes con PHP.

Comment: Precisamente quiero proveer a mis alumnos de Secundaria una forma de leer valor mientra les explico las estructuras, arrays y otros elementos del lenguaje PHP; sin necesidad del tedio de un formulario HTML.

Comment: Quita el casteo de `intval()` y la comparación de `if (!is_nan($phptemp)){` porque revisando por la web, leí que PHP hace la conversión de tipos según lo ocupe uno, a diferencia de JS que si tienes que especificar qué tipo de dato es. Haz la prueba y me dices.

Comment: Naranjas, no importa que temperatura escriba siempre la salida es que "Es un Lindo Día!!! No cambia el tipo al momento de la comparación.

Answer (score 1):

Bien la respuesta corta es: No es que PHP está convirtiendo mal a entero o tengas que usar otra función, es que tu codigo esta mal pensado. Javasctipt es CLIENTE, PHP es Servidor. Esa variable nunca llegara al servidor, y te ahora te muestro tambien porque piensas que la variable si esta en php pero en realidad no está.

Ahora veamos lo que tu codigo esta haciendo exactamente.

El problema esta en que la linea

```
$stemp = "<script> document.write(temp) </script>";
```

Estás asignando el String  document.write(temp) , literalmente te recomiendo (NUNCA PODRA SER CONVERTIDO A ENTERO ESE TEXTO, NO IMPORTA QUE FUNCION DE PHP USES) usar var_dump para analizar este tipo de situaciones.

Y si haces echo de esa variable pensaras que estoy loco y esto no es verdad porque podrás leer el valor de la temperatura pero en realidad esto pasa porque: echo está imprimiendo código en navegador (CLIENTE) y el navegador ya tiene la variable de Javascript y por eso piensas que tu codigo anda cuando en realidad nunca va a andar.

SOLUCIÓN:

Para los fines prácticos ya que planteas que quieres hacer una demo en tu escuela y no quieres meterte con Formularios o AJAX, te recomiendo una solución simple que tanto CLIENTE y SERVIDOR pueden acceder y son las COOKIES.

El problema de esta solucion que tienes que agregar más Código Javascript y tiene que forzar un reload de la página, para que la cookie se guarde en primera instancia y PHP la pueda leer en el próximo reload SI NO SIEMPRE ESTARÁS LEYENDO UN VALOR DE LA COOKIE ANTERIOR AL NUEVO CARGADO, YA QUE TODO OCURRE EN LA MISMA PÁGINA.
En fin no se si seria mas facil usar AJAX, como sea te copio como quedaría tu codigo y tu decides.

NOTA: Agregue la función crearCookie y urlCargar.
CrearCookie se autodescribe en lo que hace.

urlCargar es para mandar un parametro trivial q=1 para que sepamos que venimos de una recarga hecha por nosotros con el fin de que el valor de la cookie se guarde y php lo pueda leer, esto es cuando tu pagina PHP no contiene parámetros y si ya tiene algun parametro LO BORRARA devolviendo la URL Limpia sin parámetros para que se ejecute de nuevo el prompt de JS, por eso agregue el botón cargar de nuevo.

```
<Doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function crearCookie(nombre, valor, dias) {
            var expira;
            if (dias) {
                var date = new Date();
                date.setTime(date.getTime() + (dias * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                expira = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
            } else {
                expira = "";
            }
            document.cookie = escape(nombre) + "=" + escape(valor) + expira + "; path=/";
        }

        function urlCargar() {
            var url = window.location.href;

            // si el indice de ? es mayor a -1 quiere decir que lo encontro
            // ya tiene parametro
            if (url.indexOf('?') > -1) {
                url = url.split('?')[0];
                console.log(url);
            } else {
                url += '?q=1'
            }


            return url;
        }

        function cargarDeNuevo() {
            url = urlCargar();
            window.location.href = url;
        }


        if (location.search.indexOf('q=') < 0) {
            temp = parseInt(window.prompt('Write a temperature', ''));
            crearCookie("temperatura", temp, 2);
            url = urlCargar();
            window.location.href = url;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <?php 
    $phptemp=( int)$_COOKIE[ "temperatura"]; 
    echo "The value of \$phptemp is : $phptemp <br>"; 
    if (!is_nan($phptemp))
    { 
        if ($phptemp < 0 || $phptemp> 38)
        { 
            echo "Don't go outside, better stay in house today!!!."; 
        }
        else 
        { 
            echo "You can go outside, it's a nice day."; 
        } 
    } 
    ?>
    <br>
    <button onclick="cargarDeNuevo()">Cargar de nuevo</button>
</body>

</html>
```